# Legend dissapearing when trying to change colours to grey scale ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
graph <- structure(list(Obstacle = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Major Obstacle", 
"Minor Obstacle", "Moderate Obstacle", "No Obstacle", "Total"
), class = "factor"), `Crime = 1` = c(0.842430787355193, 0.724891824185835, 
0.692470837751856, 0.673805601317957), `Crime = 2` = c(0.157569212644807, 
0.275108175814165, 0.307529162248144, 0.326194398682043)), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
graph <- melt(graph, id="Obstacle")

            Obstacle Crime = 1 Crime = 2
1       No Obstacle 0.8424308 0.1575692
2    Minor Obstacle 0.7248918 0.2751082
3 Moderate Obstacle 0.6924708 0.3075292
4    Major Obstacle 0.6738056 0.3261944
```

If I do this, I get colours and a legend.

```
graph %>% 
  mutate(Obstacle = fct_relevel(Obstacle, "No Obstacle", "Minor Obstacle", "Moderate Obstacle", "Major Obstacle")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Obstacle, y=value, colour=variable, group = variable)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 20)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

I thought to make it black and white like this, but then the lines are identical and there is no longer a legend. What am I doing wrong?

```
graph %>% 
  mutate(Obstacle = fct_relevel(Obstacle, "No Obstacle", "Minor Obstacle", "Moderate Obstacle", "Major Obstacle")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Obstacle, y=value, fill=variable, group = variable)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 20)) +
  scale_fill_grey() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Lines don't have a fill color ...

Comment: Where is the "variable" coming from?

Comment: My apologies, I forgot the `melt` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

graph %>% 
  # reshape2::melt(graph, id="Obstacle") %>% 
  mutate(Obstacle = fct_relevel(Obstacle, "No Obstacle", "Minor Obstacle", "Moderate Obstacle", "Major Obstacle")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Obstacle, y=value, colour=variable, group = variable)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 20)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

```r
graph %>% 
  # reshape2::melt(graph, id="Obstacle") %>% 
  mutate(Obstacle = fct_relevel(Obstacle, "No Obstacle", "Minor Obstacle", "Moderate Obstacle", "Major Obstacle")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Obstacle, y=value, colour=variable, group = variable)) +
  geom_line() +  
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 20)) +
  scale_colour_grey()
```

[image]

In your second `ggplot` you mixed up `fill` and `colour`. Set up:

- `colour=variable` inside `aes` instead of `fill=variable`
- `scale_colour_grey` instead of `scale_fill_gray`

Comment: Thank you Edo! Nice that this works without melting (which I forgot to add the code).

Comment: you can either use `tidyr::pivot_longer` or `reshape2::melt`. I've commented out the reshaping, to be consistent with your question update